# White Screen on top part of iOS react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I get white screen at the top part of my iOS react native app. I have SafeAreaView as a container  housing my code. On some screens the white space is just at the top, some others, just bottom; while some top and bottom. Below is an image:

[image]

Below is what my code looks like:

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground source={backgroundImg} style={styles.image}>
        {/* arrow section */}
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.firstLevelContainer}
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
          <Image source={backIcons} style={styles.backIconsStyle}></Image>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {/* text Section */}
        <View style={styles.secondLevelContainer}>
          <CustomText
            color={colors.white}
            size={30}
            capitalize={'none'}
            fontType={fonts.nunitoBold}>
            {CapitalizeFirstLetter('Create\nan account')}
          </CustomText>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.thirdLevelContainer}>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.scrollviewContainer}>
          {Formikform()}
        </ScrollView>
        </View>
       
        <View style={styles.fourthLevelContainer}>
          <CustomText
            color={colors.white}
            size={12}
            style={{marginLeft: 10}}
            capitalize={'none'}
            fontType={fonts.nunitoLight}>
            or sign in with
          </CustomText>
          <View style={styles.displayRow}>
            <Image
              source={facebookLogo}
              style={styles.socialLoginIconSize}></Image>
            <Image
              source={googleLogo}
              style={styles.socialLoginIconSize}></Image>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

StyleSheet

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    top: 0,
  },
  formContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    marginBottom:hp(20),
    marginLeft:hp(5)
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how SafeAreaView works. If you want your image to cover all of the screen I'd suggest the following UI Hierarchy:

```
<ImageBackground>
  <SafeAreaView>
    // your content goes here
  </SafeAreaView>
</ImageBackground>
```

Checkout [this snack](https://snack.expo.io/@cjimenez/0984a0) for more details

Comment: The @Carlos. This covered the top part of the screen, but the bottom still had the white part.

Comment: @Marvelous Ikechi You need to put the SafeAreaView inside the ImageBackground

Comment: Sorry, I had done that, but reverted the code after it didn't cover the base

Comment: So, I used background colour on the parent container, and it covered the top. However, the bottom remained the same.